# When I merge dataframes using columns as a key, it repeats the other columns infinite times

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[image: The problem looks like this. I'm not sure why the columns keep repeating. I've tried merging on='company_id' and how='left' but it just won't work.]

The problem looks like this. I'm not sure why the columns keep repeating. I've tried merging on='company_id' and how='left' but it just won't work.

Below I have attached a some sample code as the people who have been helping me have requested. Hopefully this will be helpful in making the question a lot better.

*I removed the data and just decided to say that the answer is the one Anky gave below. Use the map function if there are several repetitive keys.

Comment: Could you please add your data samples as executable code instead of the images?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's data I'm not allowed to share legally :/ Would you have any idea of how I could potentially approach this issue though or what I should be looking at?

Comment: @KingAlandyDy you can create a dummy data to share, it will help us replicate the issue. BDW you have duplicate keys in second df which you are merging on.

Comment: Alright. I'll do that, right now. @anky_91, I want it to copy the description on df based on the company_id on df_2. Is it not possible to merge on duplicate keys?

Comment: @KingAlandyDy i would prefer map in such cases, check below answer.

Comment: Wow that's amazing. Thanks so much for your help! I will edit my question so that other people with the same concern will be able to figure it out. Thank you so much! Sorry, I'm a scrub. Don't know about this map function. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. :) Just to let you know for readability, avoid posting large data, a small one would help. Cheers..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html);

```
d = dict(zip(df['company_id'],df['description']))
df2['description']=df2['company_id'].map(d)
```